# Regex Expression for Pseudocode

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex expression for a project, and struggling here.

Here's my sample string:

```
[link="http://www.cnn.com"]CNN Webpage[/link]
```

I want to regex.replace the above example to this:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">CNN Webpage</a>
```

I know there is a Regex way to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer using named groups when I can. As you'll see it makes the regex/code a little more maintainable/readable. This also helps with maintenance on the code as the captured groups are no longer being referenced by the index. As you probably know, the index groups will change if you change any preceding capturing groups within the regex.

The named groups will stay consistent through the lifetime of the regex unless you specifically change it.

**Regex**

```
\[link=["\u201C](?<href>[^"\u201D]+)["\u201D]\](?<title>[^\[]+)\[/link\]
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dB0hQ7/2) - Note the regex is different because of the different regex engines, but the regex is equal to the one I present here.

**Code**

```
var str = "[link=\"http://www.cnn.com\"]CNN Webpage[/link] OR [link=“http://www.cnn.com”]CNN Webpage[/link]";

var regex = new Regex(@"\[link=[""\u201C](?<href>[^""\u201D]+)[""\u201D]\](?<title>[^\[]+)\[/link\]");

//The ${name} refers to a named capture group in the regex. Makes it a little more readable, and maintainable.
str = regex.Replace(str, "<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"_blank\">${title}</a>");

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Please note that the regex only supports the "smart quotes" if the quotes are used properly, to handle cases where the quotes might be reversed you'd need to do something like this:

```
\[link=["\u201C\u201D](?<href>[^"\u201D\u201C]+)["\u201D\u201C]\](?<title>[^\[]+)\[/link\]
```

Just for clarity, the example below shows where this regex would be useful. Notice the last link has the unicode characters messed up. It uses the unicode right quote (\u201D `”`) on both sides of the text. This regex will parse the data, but the one at the beginning of the post will not.

```
var str = "[link=\"http://www.cnn.com\"]CNN Webpage[/link] OR [link=“http://www.cnn.com”]CNN Webpage[/link]  OR [link=”http://www.cnn.com”]CNN Webpage[/link]";

var regex = new Regex(@"\[link=[""\u201C\u201D](?<href>[^""\u201D\u201C]+)[""\u201D\u201C]\](?<title>[^\[]+)\[/link\]");

//The ${name} refers to a named capture group in the regex. Makes it a little more readable, and maintainable.
str = regex.Replace(str, "<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"_blank\">${title}</a>");
```

Comment: Thanks! One question - does this Regex expression replace multiple instances of the matched expression?

Comment: Second question - Just realized some text contains the unicode "smart quotes". Therefore the regex fails matching. Can I get an amended expression for the unicode equivalents for the quotes?

Comment: @Michael: It does support multiple replacements, which should be a little clearer in the edit I did. I've also updated the answer to include the unicode quotes. The primary regex I used will only support the quotes if they appear in order (left quote and then right quote) However, at the bottom of the answer you'll find a regex that should support any combination of the unicode quotes.

Comment: Your answer is being marked because you are being so helpful and descriptive. One more question - this regex does both the smart quotes and the usual ASCII quote right?

Comment: @Michael: Yep, it'll handle both notice within the square brackets `["\u201C\u201D]`, the ASCII quote plus the unicode characters. If you need to support more quote delimiters you'd just add them to there. It'll also pick up a mix of unicode/ascii quotes within a single link.

Comment: Nathan - Sorry to bug you about this again, but can you help me figure out how to account for white spaces (leading and trailing) in both of the capture groups for this regex?

Comment: The simplest way to account for leading/trailing white space is placing this `[\t\s]*` where you wish to account for white space. This works in most cases. If you have an example of your case, I can give you a better example. However, it sounds like you want it part of the capturing group so give this a try `\[link=["\u201C](?<href>[\t\s]*[^"\u201D]+[\t\s]*)["\u201D]\](?<title>[\t\s]*[^\[]+[\t\s]*)\[/link\]` It'll grab any white space before/after the href and title, which will be included in the capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to capture the `http` link and the content of `[link]` tag.

Regex:

```
\[link="([^"]*)"\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/link]
```

Replacement string:

```
<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qZ5lC6/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
\[link(="[^"]+")\]([^\[]+)\[\/link\]
```

Try this.Replace by `<a href$1 target="_blank">$2</a>`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/18